# C# MVC - Entity Framework Not Connecting to Azure Database

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, azure-sql-database

I have created an MVC application that was pointed at a local SQL Server Express database. Everything worked fine. I then deployed my application to Azure, changing the connection string to the below.But when I debug the application, from my PC  Entity Framework seems to ignore the web.config file and tries to use SQL Server Express. I am not sure where it is picking up this connection from?

**xml code**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TrainProcess"
         connectionString="Server=tcp:traincliamapplication.database.windows.net;Database=TrainClaim;
                          User ID=xxxxxx@traincliamapplication;Password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;
                          Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you change the connection string name in your database context?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the user login xxxxxx@traincliamapplication created on the Azure SQL Database? Is that user registered on Azure Active Directory? You may want to change it for a (contained) database user.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) guide should really help you with all considerations for deploying your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the user but it still doesn't work. I will check through the guide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your IP to the firewall at: *SQL servers
(Your DB) - Firewall / Virtual Networks (Preview)*, then at your right pane you can see a message that says "Connections from the IPs specified below provides access to all the databases in (Your DB)", add your IP (check if you have a static IP from your ISP) and that's it.